# How to just have one OnClick Countdown Timer running?

Tags: android, onclick, countdowntimer

I am having trouble thinking of a way to keep only one CountdownTimer going for an onClick listener. Basically I have an application that 6 buttons and each time you hit one of the buttons it starts a countdown on the respective buttons text. However, I only want the most recent countdown started by an OnClick for each button running and updating the text on the button.

Here's the code I have so far... It works, but the countdowns start "fighting" with each other over which is altering the text of the button. Is there a way so that each time the OnClick is registered that any countdowns created by earlier button clicks are destroyed / ignored?

```
oBlue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Button was clicked so start our count down
                CountDownTimer blueTime = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
                     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                         String s = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                         oBlue.setText(s);
                     }

                     public void onFinish() {
                         oBlue.setText(String.valueOf(300));
                     }
                  }.start();
```

Comment: Have you looked at the API doc for the CountDownTimer class?  Does cancel() look like it could do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your counter variable with an internal class, so that you do not need to create counter variable each time. Just create a time counter variable and call the start of it if you want to restart the counter each button.

Es:

```
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}
```

//enter your code

Comment: Appreciate your help, I feel a little bit silly for not thinking of that. Sometimes you look too hard at things sometimes and ignore the obvious!